# How to test chained methods in Ruby on Rails using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I'm trying to decide how to test a method that simply calculates an average of values on associated records. I'm concerned about testing the implementation vs the actual result returned.

Say I have the following models...

```
class User
  has_many :interviews

  def interview_grade
    interviews.average(:score).round unless interviews.empty?
  end
end

class Interview
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And in `user_spec.rb` I have...

```
describe "interview_grade" do
  let(:user) {User.new}
  context "when the user has interviews" do
    before { user.stub_chain(:interviews, :empty?){false} }
    it "should return an average of the appraisal ratings" do
      user.interviews.should_receive(:average).with(:score).and_return(3.2)
      user.work_history_grade.should == 3
    end
  end

  context "when the user has no interviews" do
    before {Interview.destroy_all}
    it "should return nil" do
      user.interview_grade.should be_nil
    end
  end

end
```

These tests pass but it feels fragile to me. What if `interview_grade` should actually calculate the **sum** of the scores (for example). As I'm just testing that a particular chain of methods is called, this passing test wouldn't tell me that the result is actually incorrect.

I have tried stubbing `user.interviews` in order to setup the available scores for the test to work with but this seems tricky to do in Rails 3 due to the way associations are lazy loaded. i.e. I can't just create an array of Interview objects because it doesn't respond to the average `method`.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming back to this 3 years later. I would would approach it entirely differently.

The benefit of the code below is that in order to write tests for InterviewGrader I would no longer need to worry about how the scores are attained.

I just give it the scores and test it gives me the correct output.

Also I would never need to worry about the underlying implementation of InterviewGrader. However, if the logic was changed at a later date, the tests would fail.

The new `scores` method on `User` would need to be tested separately.

```
class InterviewGrader

  def self.run scores
    new(scores).run
  end

  attr_reader :scores

  def initialize(scores)
    @scores = scores
  end

  def run
    scores.inject { |sum, score|
      sum + score
    }.to_f / number_of_scores
  end

  private

  def number_of_scores
    scores.length
  end

end


class User
  has_many :interviews

  def scores
    interviews.map(&:score)
  end

  def interview_grade
    InterviewGrader.run(scores)
  end
end

class Interview
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect usage of stubbing and mocking.

In this case you should only test, that `interview_grade` works, when `average` returns nil (and this is only case `interviews.empty?` is used).

The `average` method is tested by rails itself. `round` method by ruby tests (i guess). So you not need to test this methods. This is a general idea to test only your own code.

And if you want to test, how interview_grade is calculated, you should create test data (with fixtures or factories). Because you should test separate (in some case) part of system, and in this case separation is wrong: interviews.average and interviews.empty? are dependent in your code, but in spec they independent.

```rb
def interview_grade
  interviews.average(:score).try(:round)
end
```

If you rewrite your method in this way, you no need in stubbing and mocking

Comment: I prefer the use of try here, I hadn't thought of that.

However, I'm trying to avoid using Factories because they are slow.

I would prefer to mock user.interviews but as I mentioned in the question, I haven't figured out a nice way to do that in Rails 3 due to the lazy loading of associations.